# Replace an IFrame's document with a reference to a global document

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I need to create a modal with some content that has some CSS that breaks the style of the main document, so I decided to "sandbox" the modals content by making it an iframe to a new Document. To load the modal specific css only once, I want to reuse for all modals the same document and only replace the body.

My problem: I used this code to put the global document in the IFrame (stripped to only contain relevant parts):

```js
window.newdoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Menu");
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = 'about:blank';
iframe.onload = () => {
    let node = iframe.contentDocument.importNode(newdoc.documentElement, true);
    iframe.contentDocument.replaceChild(node, iframe.contentDocument.documentElement);
}
```

The problem with that is that it uses `importNode` that clones my document. I want to use a reference zo the global document instead so that if I do `newdoc.body.innerHTML = "some html";` later, it also updates the document in the iframe. I tried following already:

```js
iframe.onload = () => {
    iframe.contentDocument.documentElement = newdoc.documentElement;
}
// And
iframe.onload = () => {
    iframe.contentDocument = newdoc;
}
```

Neither worked. Is there a way to do this? I thought about using maybe a `MutationObserver` for each IFrame but it wouldn't be as optimized as using a reference directly I think.

Comment: I'm a little confused...you want to modify the clone and not modify the original iframe?

Comment: I want the iframe to always show the current state of the global document instead of the clone. I am searching for a way to not have to clone the document but still put it into the IFrame.

Comment: How about modifying the original and placing it back when done? Do you mean to keep the changes after exiting page?

Comment: What do you mean with placing it back when done? If you mean recloning it and applying it to every iframe containing it that's what I meant with using a `MutationObserver`.

Comment: Use `adoptNode()` instead of `importNode()`. `adoptNode()` ***moves*** instead of cloning iframe content. When you say every iframe containing it...an iframe is merely a window to another page. If you have multiple iframes to the same content (ie. `src` is identical) it's still only one page that being the original one. Several iframes to the same `src` is like several windows to the same living room in the same house...

Comment: I will just use a MutationObserver.